# type mismatch found ApplicationWithFilter.this.AuthenticatedRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] required List[org.pac4j.core.profile.CommonProfile]

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to scala,pac4j & play framework. I am facing following issue

```
missing parameter type. type mismatch;
[error]  found   : ApplicationWithFilter.this.AuthenticatedRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
(which expands to)  org.pac4j.play.scala.AuthenticatedRequest[org.pac4j.core.profile.CommonProfile,play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
[error]  required: List[org.pac4j.core.profile.CommonProfile]
[error]       Ok(views.html.index(profiles, csrfToken, null))
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[missing parameter type]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:30)
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:30)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:32)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:27)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:27)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:23)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:50)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:50)***
```

Strangely there was no compilation error while i last use my workspace. I copied my workspace and then I ran sbt run instead of bin\activator run. And i started facing lot of compilation issues when I load http://localhost:9000.
I suppose these are either library issue instead of code.

please let me know what is the issue and what can be the possible fix.

Build.sbt

```
name := "play-pac4j-scala-demo"

version := "5.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

val playPac4jVersion = "5.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
val pac4jVersion = "2.2.0"
val playVersion = "2.6.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  ehcache, // or cacheApi
  ws,
  filters,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.pac4j" %% "play-pac4j" % playPac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-http" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-cas" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-openid" % pac4jVersion exclude("xml-apis" , "xml-apis"),
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-oauth" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-saml" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-oidc" % pac4jVersion exclude("commons-io" , "commons-io"),
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-gae" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-jwt" % pac4jVersion exclude("commons-io" , "commons-io"),
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-ldap" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-sql" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-mongo" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-kerberos" % pac4jVersion,
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-couch" % pac4jVersion,
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-cache_2.12" % playVersion,
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(Resolver.mavenLocal, "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases", "Sonatype snapshots repository" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/")

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

fork in run := true
```

Thanks 
Priyanka

Comment: you need to show the code so that we can help. and probably your build.sbt file

Comment: I haven't made any changes in code. It is same as PAC4j scala demo.   https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-scala-demo.  Instead of open feide , i have used wso2.. Only configuration changes.

Comment: Please find my build.sbt file